# How to setup Bash 4 and other GNU tools in MacOS based Github Action runners?

Tags: bash, macos, github, github-actions

I have several bash scripts in my project that require Bash 4, GNU sed and thelike. Setting that up on local machines is quite straightforward (updating `.bashrc`, `chsh` and thelike) but I can't seem to get MacOS based Github Actions to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The following Github Action YAML snipped will install `brew`, a newer `bash` version, GNU `sed` and put them all in the path so that the following scripts will correctly pick them up:

```
- name: Install Bash 4 and GNU sed on Mac
  run: |
    /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
    brew update

    brew install bash
    brew install gnu-sed

    echo "/usr/local/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
    echo "$(brew --prefix)/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

Make sure that all scripts have `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as their shebang as well.

Comment: How does `brew` know which version (4 or 5, etc) of bash should be installed ?

Comment: Good point, I should prolly adjust the question to say "bash > 3", since that was the actual use-case here.

Answer (score 0):

Installing bash right away is sufficient, as brew is already installed on GH runners, also it works fine with scripts using `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

```
- name: Install current Bash on macOS
  if: runner.os == 'macOS'
  run: brew install bash
```